# need help converting integers to string in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a program for my intro programming class and I need to make a calculator that prints out the results like a history. I'm doing it in a way that the first number, the arithmetic operation and second number are separate objects in a list but I need to combine them into a complete object in a list. I've tried several ways to do this but each time it will either crash or not work exactly how it should.

```
history = []
first_number = int(input("please input your first number"))
second_number = int(input("please input your second number"))
operator = input("ADD, SUBTRACT, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, CHOOSE again or STOP? ").lower()

def add():
    return(first_number + second_number)

def problemAdd(): 
    return(first_number, "+", second_number)

while operator != "stop":
    if operator == "add":
        print("the problem was:", first_number, "+", second_number, "=", add())
        history.append (problem())
        print(history)
        first_number = int(input("please input your first number"))
        second_number = int(input("please input your second number"))
        operator = input("ADD, SUBTRACT, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, CHOOSE again or STOP? ").lower()
```

Now this part of the code I hope it's enough to spot a problem. And this is what it outputs:

```
please input your first number2
please input your second number2
would you like to ADD, SUBTRACT, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, CHOOSE again or STOP? add
the problem was: 2 + 2 = 4
[(2, '+', 2)]
please input your first number1
please input your second number2
would you like to ADD, SUBTRACT, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, CHOOSE again or STOP? add
the problem was: 1 + 2 = 3
[(2, '+', 2), (1, '+', 2)]
please input your first number
```

I ran through it twice to show how each individual problem is displayed.

Comment: This isn't very clear. Give us clear input and expected output, especially if you've already got some code that's not working as intended and we can help you! If your code is crashing please include the whole traceback.

Comment: use `str`, eg. `str(0)`

Comment: great edit -- I'll get to work on tailoring my answer to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

```
# lst = [(2, '+', 2)]
for tpl in lst:
   operation = " ".join(map(str,tpl))
   # map(str, tpl) returns an object where every element in tpl is mapped
   # using the str function. str(object) returns the value of object as a
   # string.

   result = eval(operation)
   # eval IS A BAD IDEA, BUT SIMPLE TO IMPLEMENT

   print("{} = {}".format(operation, result))
```

It's a little unclear if this is what you're trying to do. I'm not sure where the `[ ..., "3 - 2 = 1"]` part from your question comes in. Maybe this will help, though?

If you only ever have two operands and one operator (e.g. everything is of the form `a ? b` where `?` is an operator, then this is much safer:

```
def do_operation(operation):
    import operator
    operand_1, operator, operand_2 = operation
    try:
        f = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub,
             "/": operator.truediv, "*": operator.mul,
             "//": operator.floordiv, "%": operator.mod}[operator]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid operator")
    return f(operand_1, operand_2)

for tpl in lst:
    operation = " ".join(map(str,tpl))
    result = do_operation(tpl)
    print("{} = {}".format(operation, result))
```

### Directly responding to your question:

```
history = []

first_number = int(input("please input your first number"))    
second_number = int(input("please input your second number"))
# what do you do if the user doesn't enter a number? Your program crashes

operator = input("ADD, SUBTRACT, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, CHOOSE again or STOP? ").lower()
op_mapping = {"add":"+", "subtract":"-", "divide":"/", "multiply":"*"}

if operator in op_mapping: # this will exclude 'choose' and 'stop'
    operator = op_mapping[operator]
elif operator == 'choose': # handle it
elif operator == 'stop': # handle it, these are up to you
else: # invalid input, handle it.

# NEW
operation = (first_number, operator, second_number)
# this makes it easier to refer to all three at once.

def calculate(operation):
    """Calculates the result based on which operator is used"""
    import operator
    operand_1, operator, operand_2 = operation
    try:
        f = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub,
             "/": operator.truediv, "*": operator.mul,
             "//": operator.floordiv, "%": operator.mod}[operator]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid operator")
    return f(operand_1, operand_2)

## while operator != "stop": # you're gonna handle this above

## if operator == "add": # we modified it so our mapping handles all if cases
##     print("the problem was:", first_number, "+", second_number, "=", add())  
##     history.append (problem())  
##     print(history)  
##     first_number = int(input("please input your first number"))    
##     second_number = int(input("please input your second number"))  
##     operator = input("ADD, SUBTRACT, DIVIDE, MULTIPLY, CHOOSE again or STOP? ").lower()

human_readable = " ".join(map(str,operation))
history.append(human_readable)
print("{} = {}".format(human_readable, calculate(operation))
print(history)

# LOOP AS NEEDED, IMPLEMENTED BY YOU.
```

Mind you if I were to do a complete rewrite it would probably look like:

```
def get_input():
    """Get user input for the calculation"""
    inputprompt = """Return the result of a calculation, based on user input.
Your input must be of the form X ? Y where X, Y are any number and ? is one of:
+, -, /, //, *, %
Please include spaces between operand and operator, or STOP to stop.

>> """
    return input(inputprompt)

def calculate(operation):
    """Calculates the result based on which operator is used"""
    import operator
    operand_1, operator, operand_2 = operation
    try:
        operand_1, operand_2 = float(operand_1), float(operand_2)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid operand")
    try:
        f = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub,
             "/": operator.truediv, "*": operator.mul,
             "//": operator.floordiv, "%": operator.mod}[operator]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid operator")
    return f(operand_1, operand_2)

def main():
    from collections import deque
    history = deque()
    # a deque is a list that allows easy popping and appending from left OR right
    MAX_HISTORY_LENGTH = 10
    while True
        print("CALCULATOR:\n\n")
        readable = get_input()
        if "stop" in readable.lower():
            break
        operation = readable.split()
        history.append(readable)
        if len(history) > MAX_HISTORY_LENGTH:
            history.popleft()
        print("{} = {}".format(readable, calculate(operation))
        input(" ( press ENTER to continue ) ")

main()
# we love functional programming!
```

Comment: +1 For stating that `eval()` is a bad idea but easy…

Comment: in this case what is "tpl" and "lst"

Comment: @AdamSmith thank you for the help this definitely gives me a cleaner way of doing this. i appreciate the help